# Defender for DevOps suppressions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-defender

In our yaml pipeline we are using the [Microsoft DevOps security](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-securitydevops.microsoft-security-devops-azdevops) extension, which is part of the Defender for cloud suite. The extension flags some json content as exposed credentials, but it's actually not. I would like to add suppressions to ignore such false positives but the documentation is limited.

There are very few [examples on how to achieve that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/detect-exposed-secrets#suppress-false-positives) using inline comments but json doesn't allow comments in such form:

```
#[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CS001:SecretInLine", Justification="... .")]
```

The extension uses the CredScan tool under the hood so it should be possible to [pass a file with suppressions](https://secdevtools.azurewebsites.net/helpcredscan.html) as a parameter, but the documentation doesn't show how to do that in the MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1 task.